# Appearance Menu - Add new items to the top of the menu

Tags: wordpress

When adding a new new menu item on the appearance menu page (/wp-admin/nav-menus.php) is it possible that when you click the Add to Menu button that the new item would be added to the top of the menu rather than the bottom?

By default, the new menu item gets added to the bottom of the new menu.

Before Add to Menu

[image: Before Add to Menu]

After Add to Menu - If possible

[image: After Add to Menu - If possible]

I can see in the Wordpress core file wp-includes/nav-menu.js there is functionality for adding the menu to either the top or the bottom but I can't see if there is a way to interact with this.

Comment: You can drag and drop the menu items.

Comment: Yes, that's true but I am looking for the item to be placed automatically at the top of the menu if possible